Sending JSON message with GET throws "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type."
var request = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Get, url );
request.Content = new StringContent( json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json" );
client.SendAsync(request);

I am trying to call an external REST API, but SendAsync() throws "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.".
The external API awaits a JSON with the GET method. I know this is not common.
It is working with Postman, though.
How can I make it work with .NET?
Edit:
The API documentation says:
Method: GET
URL: http://server/api/organization/status/39bd8abc-6022-44e9-8a70-ed4830b8afc1
Authentication: Bearer
Header:
Key: X-Request-Partner
Value: 7e884abc-2cd9-4990-a559-18f7def375e9
Body (raw JSON):
{
"Fields": [
{
  "Name": "IdPerson",
  "ObjectType": "Person"
},
{
  "Name": "IdCard",
  "ObjectType": "PersonBadgeNumber"
},
{
  "Name": "BookingDateTime",
  "ObjectType": "DataExchangePersonalStatusLastBookingTime"
},
{
  "Name": "TerminalApiKey",
  "ObjectType": "DataExchangePersonalStatusLastTerminal",
  "Representation": "Naming"
},
{
  "Name": "Status",
  "ObjectType": "DataExchangePersonalStatusActual",
  "Replacements": {
    "DefaultValue": "Abwesend",
    "ReplaceBy": [
      {
        "SearchValue": "Present",
        "ReplaceBy": "Anwesend"
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
}


Why you want to send content using GET method? Normally GET method works when you want to retrieve some data from API call. If you need sending data to API you should use POST or PUT methods

I know that. But as I said it is an external API. I can't change this.

have you the external API specs to understand how implement it?

I added the "documentation"...

try pass fields as form-params defining a List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>

It is working with https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/

It is working with https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/ ............

Please try to provide some explanation for future readers.
